# Convert RSA pair to pem filezilla compatible key on linux

Tags: linux, ssh-keygen, filezilla

I have a pair of keys generated using: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/keys/my_key -C "blah@gmail.com"`. This yielded 2 files `my_key` and `my_key.pub`.

Now I need to convert that pair to a `.pem` key that is *filezilla* compatible (to connect over sftp).

I already tried something like `ssh-keygen -f my_key -m 'PEM' -e > my_key.pem` but *filezilla* kept complaining `It doesn't contain a private key`.

I am running *Ubuntu 22.04 x64*.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For OpenSSH 7.8 up, which includes your 8.9) from `man ssh-keygen` or [on the web](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1)

> -e
> This option will read a private or public OpenSSH key file and print to stdout a public key in one of the formats specified by the -m option. ...

Note the words 'public key'. To authenticate yourself, which is what you want FileZilla to do, you need the private key not (just) the public key.

> -m key_format
> Specify a key format for key generation, the -i (import), -e (export) conversion options, and the -p change passphrase operation. The latter may be used to convert between OpenSSH private key and PEM private key formats. ...

As it says, use `ssh-keygen -p -f .../my_key -m pem` to 'change' the password -- it needn't really change, you can enter the new password the same as the old one, but regardless `ssh-keygen` re-writes the private key file in the desired format. (Since this overwrites the previous file, if you want to also keep the OpenSSH-new-format version, make a backup before doing this operation, or do it on a copy.)

For completeness, if you have (or get) (new enough) Putty, its utility puttygen can convert OpenSSH-new-format to either OpenSSL-PEM *or* Putty-PPK formats, both of which FileZilla can read.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried many variations of this command in vain. Now it works. Finally, I wonder if there's a way to generate it to a new file rather than overriding the old one to avoid doing it by mistake...

Comment: Enissay: you can _generate_ a key in 'old'=OpenSSL format with e.g. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m pem [-f filename] [-C comment]`. But that wasn't in your Q.

Comment: That would be a different key... I was just hoping for safety for a way to avoid crushing my key by mistake... I kept a note and hope for the best xD

Comment: Sorry: I missed new _file_; in cryptospeak 'generate' always means a new key. No, `-p` always rewrites the same (preexisting) file, so as I said make a backup or copy _first_ if you want.